# How to get unblocked after excessive web scraping?

Tags: web-scraping

I was being lazy and did a lot of very rapid scraping. Now I'm blocked from the site (yelp.com). Is there a way to get unblocked?

I have tried contacting customer support, but I'm looking for a way to do this on my own.

Comment: Any reason for not using Yelp's API? https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3

Comment: Because I was being lazy...

Answer (score 1):

Change your ip address / use a vpn

Comment: How do I change my IP address to something that's still valid?

Comment: Do you have a static or dynamic ip address?

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: Open a command prompt and check if dhcp is enabled using the command ipconfig /all

Comment: This doesn't seem like the right command. I get back `usage: ipconfig <command> <args>
where <command> is one of waitall, getifaddr, ifcount, getoption, getpacket, getv6packet, set, setverbose`